# Finding the derivative of 7x^2cos(6x-2)

Tags: derivatives

I'm having trouble finding the derivative given that it is a multiple choice answer.

From my working so far I get:

You differentiate the 7x^2 part into 14x.
Then using the chain rule you differentiate the cos(6x-2) part into -sin(6x-2)(6) > -6sin(6x-2).

I then put it together and got 14x(-6sin(6x-2)) > -14x(6sin(6x-2)). And I have this as my final answer.

However it doesn't match any of the answer provided in the multiple choice as it is asking for the answer in the form.

(One of the answers provided out of 5)

-14(3cos(6x-2)x+sin(6x-2)

Edit:

Using (fg)'x = f(x)g'(x) + f'(x)g(x)

f(x) = 7x^2

g(x) = cos(6x-2)

(fg)'x = (7x^2)(-6sin(6x-2)) + (14x)(cos(6x-2))

=  -42sin(6x-2)x^2 + 14cos(6x-2)X

=  14x(-3sin(6x-2)x + cos(6x-2)

Which should be the answer?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the product rule incorrectly. What you've written amounts to $(fg)'(x) = f'(x)g'(x)$, but the correct statement is
$$(fg)'(x) = f(x)g'(x) + f'(x)g(x),$$
so that the right answer is
$$7x^2(-6\sin(6x-2)) + 14x(\cos(6x-2)).$$

Comment: Thanks. So I assume I multiply out taking out the common factor to get the answer on the form asked.

Comment: The answer you gave in the question doesn't appear to be the correct one.

Comment: Yea I know I just used it as an example of one of them to show the form the answer is required in